# Show hide div through checkbox in JQuery

Tags: jquery

JQuery:

```
$('#chkCaption').live("click", function() {
    if ($('#chkCaption').attr("checked")) {
        $('#divCaption').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#divCaption').hide();
    }
});
```

But it is not work.Help to find my mistake or suggest the way.Thanks.

Comment: a lots of similar questions are here..

Comment: what doesn't work exactly ?? .show may be .show()

Comment: I suggest this read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: show your HTML (best in a jsfiddle), that would at least help... but you should tell us what's wrong!

Comment: Prob is Once check box is checked its not unchecked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#chkCaption').live("click", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#divCaption').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#divCaption').hide();
    }
});
```

this should be in document.ready.

Instead of Jquery `attr` or `is` you can use javascript property `checked`

Comment: Its seems browser prob but its work D:) its perfect what i want.Thanks.

Comment: +1 using `this.checked` instead of `.is(':checked')`, -1 for using obsolete `.live()`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
$('#chkCaption').attr('checked')
```

you may want to try this:

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot the function declaration parens on show()

```
$('#chkCaption').live("click", function() {
    if ($('#chkCaption').attr("checked")) {
        $('#divCaption').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#divCaption').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery 1.9 .live() was removed. So the actual answers changed, if using javascript .checked:

```
$('#chkCaption').on("click", function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#divCaption').show("table-row");
  }
  else {
    $('#divCaption').hide();
  }
});
```

In pure jQuery:

```
$('#chkCaption').on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#divCaption').show();
  }
  else {
    $('#divCaption').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#chkCaption').click(function () {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

            //Show div
        } else {
            //Hide div
        }
});
```

That should do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `()`, TRY

```
$('#chkCaption').live("click", function() {
    if ($('#chkCaption').prop("checked")) {
        $('#divCaption').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#divCaption').hide();
    }
});
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/NpKJ9/)

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#chkCaption').live("click", function() {
    if ($('#chkCaption').is(":checked")) {
        $('#divCaption').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#divCaption').hide();
    }
});
```